# str_replace / strtr and Replacement Character

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I want to replace some useless characters with strtr or str_replace (error is the same with both)

Here a test with deux useless characters:

U+201E : DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK („)

U+00AF : MACRON (¯)

```
<?php

$string = "This „ is a ­ test";

$string = strtr($string, chr(ord("„")), " ");
$string = strtr($string, chr(ord("­")), " ");

echo $string;
```

In result, I got `This �� is a � test` with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (Unicode U+FFFD)

What are they, and how delete them ?

Comment: php string functions aren't unicode aware. you're mangling your text. that's why there's the `mb_*()` versions, which ARE multi-byte aware.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're calling `strtr` it will translate "characters" one by one, and since it's not encoding aware a "character" for it is a byte. This will mangle multi-byte strings.

Further, `chr(ord())` is pretty pointless, and further mangles your data. `ord` just translates a single byte to a single integer, and `chr` does the reverse. These functions are useless for your purpose, and cannot handle multi-byte strings either.

Simply do:

```
str_replace(array('„', "\xC2\xAF"), ' ', $string)
```

`str_replace` isn't encoding-aware either, but it does not "do" anything with the given strings, it merely looks for the exact byte patterns to replace. This is a safe operation with UTF-8.

I've placed the literal "„" character above, but encoded the macron using the byte notation. Since macron is a combining character, it can be otherwise problematic to see or handle in source code as a literal. If your source code file is saved as UTF-8 and `$string` is also UTF-8 encoded, this will do just fine.

If this does not replace the desired characters, then those exact characters aren't in your string. Inspect your string using `bin2hex` to see what exact bytes it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you are working with multybyte strings.

`strtr` treats one byte as one character which is not safe with your encoding. You need to use multibyte string functions http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php or specify the byte sequences you want to replace and use a binary safe string function on it, for example `str_replace`